# Were 10 ISIS fighters/members crossing from Mexico to US caught by US security forces in 2014?

Tags: united-states, isis

In October 2014, [Donald Trump tweeted](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/519962130859429888):

> The fight against ISIS starts at our border. "At least" 10 ISIS have been caught crossing the Mexico border. Build a wall!

What, if any, evidence is there for this claim?

Comment: Oh man! 2014 called Trump, it wants its dated news reports back. [Here's the reporting on the original source (Congressman Hunter)](http://www.foxnews.com/politics/2014/10/08/congressman-at-least-10-isis-fighters-caught-trying-to-cross-into-us.html?) . [Here's another, farm more general (non ISIS specific) claim from 2016 that's actually true](http://www.politifact.com/florida/statements/2016/apr/04/ron-desantis/terrorists-groups-besides-isis-crossing-us-mexico-/)

Comment: DHS has denied that ISIS report... but we are talking about DHS reporting to Obama, so they are a wee bit incentivized to deny the report (the fact that Politifact tactfully decided to omit from their analysis).

Comment: A separate report does show ISIS presence in Mexico: http://www.judicialwatch.org/blog/2016/04/cartels-help-terrorists-in-mexico-get-to-u-s-to-explore-targets-isis-militant-shaykh-mahmood-omar-khabir-among-them/

Comment: Actually, I take that first comment back. The tweet is from 2014.

Comment: The Judicial Watch's sources seem to be an Italian newspaper article that is untranslated and its own articles. Perhaps there could be a better source?  Also, I don't think the very fact that Obama is President is cause enough to dismiss PF's article.

Comment: @user5341: Sounds like you have enough evidence to turn that into an answer...